# How to upgrade ruby without package managers in Gitlab Server?

Tags: ruby

I'm upgrading Ruby on my Gitlab Server from 2.7.2 to 2.7.4. But I'm not able to see the upgraded version on the Admin Area Dashboard. It still shows the earlier version and when I do a ruby gem list it tells that all the gems have not been got according to the new package. I'm upgrading ruby without any package manager, i.e. from the source. Kindly help me.

Comment: Please clarify the steps you took or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what caused the problem.